# Website to computer communications

Tags: php, python, web

I am working on my senior project at university and I have a question. My advisor and other workers don't know much more on the matter so I thought I would toss it out to SO and see if you could help.

We want to make a website that will be hosted on a server that we are configuring. That website will have buttons on it, and when visitors of that website click a certain button we want to register an event on the server. We plan on doing this with PHP.

Once that event is registered (this is where we get lost), we want to communicate with a serial device on a remote computer. We are confident we can set up the PHP event/listener for the button press, but once we have that registered, how do we signal to the remote computer(connected via T1 line/routers) to communicate with the serial device? What is this sequence of events referred to as? The hardest thing for us (when researching it) is that we are not certain what to search for!

We have a feeling that a python script could be running on the server, get signals from the PHP listener, and then communicate with the remote PC. The remote PC could also be running a python script that then will communicate with our serial device. Again, most of this makes sense, but we are not clear on how we communicate between Python and PHP on the web server (or if this is possible).

If any one could give me some advice on what to search for, or similar projects I would really appreciate it. Thanks,

Comment: clarified it a bit. The remote PC is a computer in a different location that has a serial device hooked up to it. We want the button presses to signal to the remote computer to communicate with the serial device. The web server and remote PC will be connected via ethernet.

Comment: What OS is loaded on the web server and the remote PC?

Comment: Centos will be loaded on the webserver, most likely ubuntu will be on the remote PC, but possibly windows...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both php and python can communicate via sockets, so I guess that is a good bet.

In PHP, when you receive the signal from the click button, open a socket to your python app with [socket_create](http://php.net/socket_create).

In python, you would need to implement a server socket ([SocketServer](http://docs.python.org/library/socketserver.html)) that listens for a connection.

Try reading up on sockets communication in general and socket programming in php and python specifically.

Comment: This makes sense, I have had some experience with sockets and I can see how this could work with some more investigation. Thank you for providing me with a good place to start looking!

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a web server also on the remote computer, perhaps using the same software as on the public server, so you do not need to learn another technology. The public server can make HTTP requests and the remote server responds by communicating with the serial device.